# What is the right way for changing the value of an already instantiated instance variable?

Tags: java, instance-variables

If I have an instance variable which has private visibility should I use a setter to change its value, or simply change the value directly?

The instance variable in this example will only ever be changed in this class, and thus the setter would be private. I assume using the setter is the right way as it localizes how/when it is changed, but its just something that is bugging me for some reason!

Please see below for code which may help convey my question clearer

```
public class A {

private int i;

public A() {
   i = 5
}

private void doSomeCalculationsA() {
   //work done here which results in the value of i being directly changed
   i = 7
}

private void doSomeCalculationsB() {
   //work done here which results in change value of i being changed via the setter
   setI(5)
}

private void setI(int newValue) {
   i = newValue;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm a huge fan of OOP, but skip the setter.  The point of setters is so that you can refactor the code without breaking _external_ users of your class.  Private methods are, by definition, internal users of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to think that simpler is clearer most of the time. If your setI is only ever going to be a setter, I wouldn't have it. If you want to imply that the method could do something more one day, you might consider having one, but for me [YAGNI](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) is the best approach.

> "Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them."

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in having a private setter/getter unless some operation/computation is actually done in the function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two considerations here - readability and rigidity.  If this variable is truly private, then directly accessing the variable is perfectly fine.  It makes the variable reference more readable because there's no question how the reference works and what it's referencing.  It's clear at a glance that this must be an instance variable.

In the past, I used to recommend writing accessors for private variables because if you ever needed to change the way that the value is fetched (even privately) then having tons of direct references may make the problem intractable.  This is the problem of rigidity.  Nowadays, we have refactoring tools which can abstract a variable with one menu item so if you ever need to create and call accessors, it's not hard to do.  So, I've changed my recommendation to prefer the simplicity and readability of direct references rather than accessing methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to call `setter/getter` on member variables of `Java POJO` class, in your case I would suggest to use `setter`

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if, the variable is not accessed from the outside (i.e. another object requesting its value), then modifying it internally is acceptable.  Otherwise, you would have to use accessors/mutators.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to have a setter is if you need to do some additional changes or calculations when you change a variable or to provide limited access to the variable from an outside class. In this case it makes no difference whatsoever, but it adds the extra time needed to call the method.

Comment: The performance difference is negligible. Due to JIT inlining, method calls are practically free in Java.

Comment: The cost to the developers' efficiency is far more important than the cost to your CPU. ;)

Comment: Obviously, but there is some minor overhead so you might as well mention it.

Comment: For any normal program the overhead of calling a method is negligible, but if one were to be doing some major data processing, it would be more efficient without a method call every time the program wants to access a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend based if another object outside can change its value. For example, the `ArrayList` class has `size` attribute with private setter for `add` and `remove` operations while the getter is public. If another objects can change its value immediately, then your setter should be public.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to have a setter, but I would not be feeling I'm doing something wrong without it, as I can add it later only if it needs some action before setting (e.g. validation)

In OOP terms, since you are still "encapsulated" behind your object's black box, I'm not sure it really matters, and not having a setter is still fine.

I would just try and keep it consistent, and make sure that you have working software as the measurement of progress.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clear winner here, it is a question of style. Many people prefer using a setter, even within the class, saying that it gives a single point of change enabling e.g. validation, and it is easier to follow who changes the value of the field. With modern IDEs though IntelliSense works either way, and IMHO in most of the cases no validation will ever be needed, so preparing for it may be a mild case of speculative generality. So sometimes it is simpler just to set the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I would use a method is if one variable is related to second variable which must be changed at the same time (think about threading & concurrency issues).